# Showing month value when no data exists SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a SQL Server 2012 table that holds session per user and I need to find out monthly total of minutes for activity and if there are no results for the month then to show "0". Table below:

```
User   SessionStart              SessionEnd
1      2014-03-01 08:00:00.000   2014-03-01 08:10:00.000
1      2014-03-15 09:00:00.000   2014-03-15 09:30:00.000
1      2014-05-01 04:00:00.000   2014-05-01 04:50:00.000
1      2014-06-01 02:00:00.000   2014-06-01 02:05:00.000
1      2014-07-01 09:00:00.000   2014-07-01 10:30:00.000
1      2014-09-01 01:00:00.000   2014-09-01 01:07:00.000
1      2014-12-05 08:00:00.000   2014-12-05 08:10:00.000
2      2014-01-01 01:01:00.000   2014-01-01 01:11:00.000
1      2015-03-01 08:00:00.000   2015-03-01 08:10:00.000
1      2015-05-01 04:00:00.000   2015-05-01 04:50:00.000
1      2015-06-01 02:00:00.000   2015-06-01 02:05:00.000
...    ...                       ...
```

What I'm ending up with is:

```
User   Month   Year   Minutes 
1      3       2014   40
1      5       2014   50  
1      6       2014   5
1      7       2014   90
1      9       2014   7
1      12      2014   10
1      3       2015   10
1      5       2015   50
1      6       2015   5
```

What I'd like to get:

```
User   Month   Year   Minutes 
1      1       2014   0
1      2       2014   0
1      3       2014   40
1      4       2014   0
1      5       2014   50  
1      6       2014   5
1      7       2014   90
1      8       2014   0
1      9       2014   7
1      10      2014   0
1      11      2014   0
1      12      2014   10
1      1       2015   0
1      1       2015   0
1      3       2015   10
1      4       2015   0
1      5       2015   50
1      6       2015   5
```

I've tried using:

```
SELECT User
      ,MONTH(SessionStart)
      ,YEAR(SessionStart)
      ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, SessionStart, SessionEnd)) AS Minutes
FROM SessionTable
WHERE User = 1 AND YEAR(SessionStart) >= 2014
GROUP BY SessionStart, User
```

I have a table called "Months" that holds the number of the month (Month) and name of the month (MonthName) and have tried performing a left outer join on this table and have also tried using case selects. I've searched on this issue on Stackoverflow and see somewhat similar issues, but not one that involves using the date. Struggling to think today...

Comment: Did you try selecting from the `Months` table and then using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your `SessionTable` (A bad name for a table, IMO - of course it's a "table")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all the rows with a `cross join` and then use `left join` to bring in your summaries.  Assuming that some row exists for each month, you can get this information from the session table itself:

```
SELECT u.User, yyyymm.mm, yyyymm.yy
       COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, s.SessionStart, s.SessionEnd)), 0) AS Minutes
FROM (SELECT 1 as user) u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(SessionStart) as yyyy, MONTH(SessionStart) as mm
      FROM SessionTable
      WHERE SessionStart >= '2014-01-01'
     ) yyyymm LEFT JOIN
     SessionStart ss
     ON u.user = ss.user AND
        YEAR(SessionStart) = yyyymm.yy AND MONTH(SessionStart) = yyyymm.mm
GROUP BY u.User, yyyymm.yyyy, yyyymm.mm;
```

Comment: So far, this is working like a champ. I do have thousands of rows and am able to pull the year/month from itself. Never ever thought about something like that! I changed a couple of the variables around and its pulling exactly the way I was hoping...

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your `months` table. Could you post your example that's not working using the left outer join?  If you start with `months` and left outer join to your `SessionTable` you should be fine.

Something like...

```
SELECT User
      ,MONTH(m.month)
      ,YEAR(m.year)
      ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, s.SessionStart, s.SessionEnd)) AS Minutes
FROM Months m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SessionTable s
    ON m.year = s.year
    AND m.month = s.month
    AND s.User = 1 
WHERE YEAR(m.year) >= 2014
GROUP BY s.SessionStart, s.User
```

NOTE:

- Don't filter your `sessionTable` data in the where clause when you're using `month` as the primary data source - filter it in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  If you put it in the `WHERE`, you're turning things into an `INNER JOIN`.
- You want to use your `months` table when returning your data for the month/year info

That work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a table with the years listed. In your example, you have me matching years on the "Months" table. Using your example, I still get the data returning without the months I want to have a "0" for. I may have to create another table for years as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a calendar table which is generally a list of predefined dates with in some range..

You need to have months table for your need..which can be generated using numbers table ..

This is a Pseudo code only:

```
create table months
(
monthdate datetime
)

insert into monthdate
select dateadd(day,n,getdate()-10000)
from numbers
where n<=10000
```

Now you have months table ,all you need to do is a left join

```
select *
from monthstable mt
join yourtable yt
on yt.date=mt.date
```

This way you will preserve all dates which you dont have as well

** some good links :**
 http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/